# Существует ли навигатор по сторонним пакетам Angular?

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular, angular4, angular5

Уже всю ПС перерыл, но так и не нашел сайта посвященного подборке angular модулей

***Ищу подобный сайт:***

- *ReactJS:* https://react.parts
- *Vue:* https://vuecomponents.com & https://madewithvuejs.com
- *Meteor:* https://atmospherejs.com

Comment: .....github? :)

Answer (score 0):

- Проекты выполненные на Angular - https://www.madewithangular.com
- Еще подборка проектов на Angular - https://angularexpo.com
- Поиск NG компонентов - https://ngx.tools/
- Подборка помпонентов *(немного устарела)* - https://github.com/brillout/awesome-angular-components